# How to know whether libpython27.a is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: python, static-libraries, 32bit-64bit, platform

I have a `libpython27.a` file: how to know whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit, on Windows 7 x64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `dumpbin /headers "libpython27.a"`. ([dumpbin reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx))

The output will contain

`FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)`

or

`FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)`

---

Note that if you get an error message like:

```
E:\temp>dumpbin /headers "libpython27.a"
LINK: extra operand `libpython27.a'
Try `LINK --help' for more information.
```

It means there is a copy of the GNU link utility somewhere in the search path. Make sure you use the correct `link.exe` (e.g. the one provided in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin`). It also requires `mspdb80.dll`, which is in the same folder or something in PATH, otherwise you'll get the error message:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When starting the Python interpreter in the terminal/command line you may also see a line like:

> Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit
>   (AMD64)] on win32

Where [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] means 64-bit Python.

Or

Try using ctypes to get the size of a void pointer:

```
import ctypes
print ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp)
```

It'll be 4 for 32 bit or 8 for 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can use: `objdump -a libpython27.a|grep 'file format'`.

Example:

```
f@f-VirtualBox:/media/code$ objdump -a libpython27.a|grep 'file format'
dywkt.o:     file format pe-i386
dywkh.o:     file format pe-i386
dywks01051.o:     file format pe-i386
dywks01050.o:     file format pe-i386
dywks01049.o:     file format pe-i386
dywks01048.o:     file format pe-i386
[...]
```